# JObject Parse Data with a variable as the value

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, algolia

I am trying to decipher the correct syntax for using JObject Parse when I need to have one of the values set by a variable. This is for using Algolia to push a new object to my search index.

```
songIndexHelper.PartialUpdateObject(JObject.Parse(@"{""ApprovalFL"":"true",
                        ""objectID"":"'+Accepted.Value+'"}"));
```

I receive `Accepted.Value` from my function argument. For example, Accepted.Value could equal something like 98. Also, `true` should be formatted as boolean instead of a string. The above is my attempt. How should I fix my syntax?

I'm following this documentation from Algolia: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/partial-update-objects/

For more context, here is the above line in the function:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? Accepted, int? Denied)
{
    var accountInfo = EntityDataAccess.GetAccountInfoByUserID(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    if(accountInfo == null || accountInfo.AdminFL == false || accountInfo.LabelFL == true)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        if(Accepted != null)
        {
            EntityDataAccess.AcceptSong(Accepted.Value);
            var songIndexHelper = HttpContext.Application.Get("SongIndexHelper") as IndexHelper<SongAlgoliaModel>;
            songIndexHelper.PartialUpdateObject(JObject.Parse(@"{""ApprovalFL"":""true"",
                                    ""objectID"":""Accepted.Value""}"));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
songIndexHelper.PartialUpdateObject(JObject.Parse(@"{""ApprovalFL"":""true"",
                                ""objectID"":""Accepted.Value""}"));
```

should be:

```
songIndexHelper.PartialUpdateObject(JObject.Parse(@"{""ApprovalFL"":true,
    ""objectID"":" +Accepted.Value+ "}"));
```

The key is to use `+` to concatenate in the value of `Accepted`, and not wrap `true` in quotes.

Another approach I would suggest is **not using strings at all**. Consider an approach like:

```
var bob = new { ApprovalFL = true, objectID = Accepted.Value};
var obj = JObject.FromObject(bob);
songIndexHelper.PartialUpdateObject(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should produce what you are looking for:

```
String json = "{\"ApprovalFL\":true,\"objectID\":" + Accepted.Value.ToString() + "}";
```

which is:

```
{"ApprovalFL":true,"objectID":98}
```

Comment: thanks for indicating the boolean. do I simply throw that String variable into where I have my razor syntax in the `JObject.Parse`?

Comment: Great answer @TommsoBelluzzo .