# Cannot implicitly convert anonymous type to System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, asp.net, algolia

I am trying to add an object to my Algolia database using a slightly different structure provided by the documentation so that I don't have to type out the Json object in string format, however I ran into an error stating

> Cannot implicitly convert anonymous type to
>   System.Collections.Generic.List

I see the red error message for all of the key/values in the `objs` variable.

```
var songIndexHelper = HttpContext.Application.Get("SongIndexHelper") as IndexHelper<SongAlgoliaModel>;

List<JObject> objs = new List<JObject>();

objs = new
{
    ApprovalFL = false,
    FreeFL = album.FreeFL,
    LicenseFL = album.LicenseFL,
    AccountInfoID = album.AccountInfoID,
    AlbumID = album.AlbumID,
    SongID = song.SongID,
    BPM = song.BPM,
    AccountImageURL = album.AccountInfo.ImageURL,
    AccountType = "Artist",
    AlbumName = album.AlbumName,
    Artist = artist,
    FeaturedArtist = songArtistsList,
    ImageURL = album.ImageURL,
    iTunesURL = album.iTunesURL,
    LabelName = album.LabelName,
    Title = album.AlbumName,
    UserID = album.AccountInfo.UserID,
    UploadDate = song.UploadDate,
    Duration = song.Duration,
    objectID = song.SongID
};

songIndexHelper.AddObjects(objs);
```

Here's the reference to documentation: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/add-objects/

**Edit** alternative method however, my formatting of LicenseFL is off

```
List<JObject> objs = new List<JObject>();
objs.Add(JObject.Parse(@"{""ApprovalFL"":false, ""FreeFL"":" + album.FreeFL + ",""LicenseFL"":" +album.LicenseFL+ "}"));

songIndexHelper.AddObjects(objs);
```

Comment: A) `objs` is a `List<JObject>`
B) You are reassigning it an instance of an anonymous type -- which is not a list
C) Even if it were a list, it would not be a list of `JObject`

1) You'd need to convert your anonymous type into a `JObject` (`JObject.FromObject(...)` might suffice)
2) You'd need to add that to the list, rather than re-assigning the list

Comment: @KirkWoll thanks for the help so far, I was referencing a suggestion from a question I asked earlier today (his second method), found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47859205/6480913 in an attempt to get this to work properly in a different situation

Comment: @mjwills to be honest, might be more straightforward from a string json standpoint. But yet again my formatting is off on the json `LicenseFL`. States it is expecting a comma after the String `LicenseFL` key (updated original question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Algolia docs](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-csharp) are unfortunately focused on the use of `JObject` (and JSON strings) which makes it reasonably easy to make mistakes (e.g. invalid JSON).

This is an [approach](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateJsonAnonymousObject.htm) you might like to consider:

```
var anon = new
{
    ApprovalFL = true,
    // Any other properties here
    objectID = song.SongID
};

var obj = JObject.FromObject(anon);
var objs = new List<JObject> { obj };
songIndexHelper.AddObjects(objs);
```

Now you get some level of safety due to the [`anon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) variable (e.g. don't have to worry about invalid JSON strings) but also easy interaction with the Algolia API (which is documented in terms of `JObject`).